# Spring Boot Config Server Property File Name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configserver

I want load application properties using spring boot config server using file system. I am able to read config files like {appname}{profile}.properties using my code. But as per the requirement I need to read properties files with the file name as {appname}.properties.{profile}. I  want to know is there any way around to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to run your app by specifying the renamed properties file as an argument

`java -jar {your_app.jar} --spring.config.name={your_app_properties_filename}`

so something like

```
java -jar App.jar --spring.config.name=App.properties.prod
```

where

```
appname=App, profile=prod
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but is this possible using spring boot config server. My application configured as config client.